# Why am I getting a syntax error from | in this script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am getting an error from this script

```
#!/bin/bash

red="\033[31m"
green="\033[32m"
yellow="\033[33m"
blue="\033[34m"
pink="\033[35m"
cyan="\033[36m"
white="\033[37m"
echo ""
echo -e  "${green}       _ __  ___ ___ "
echo -e  "${green}      | '_ \/ __/ __|"
echo -e  "${green}      | | | \__ \__ \"
echo -e  "${green}      |_| |_|___/___/"
echo -e "${blue}        Welcome My first program"
echo ""
```

Error given to me by the system

```
./my_first_program.sh: Line 14: unexpected token `| ' Syntax error near
./my_first_program.sh: Line 14: `echo -e  "${green} |_| |_|___/___/"'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) can point out this error, as well as many other kinds of errors. The script raises [SC1078](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1078)/[SC1079](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1079).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the line

```
echo -e  "${green}      | | | \__ \__ \"
```

the `\` before the `"` removes the special meaning of the `"` and makes it a normal character that doesn't end the string. So the string continues to the next line until the `"` before `${green}` and the following `${green}      |_| |_|___/___/` isn't quoted any more, which causes the error.

Add a space after the `\` to prevent it from escaping the `"`:

```
echo -e  "${green}      | | | \__ \__ \ "
```

Comment: +1 ... or escape the backslash itself i.e. `echo -e  "${green}      | | | \__ \__ \\"`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I made modifications to your script and here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

red="\033[31m"
green="\033[32m"
yellow="\033[33m"
blue="\033[34m"
pink="\033[35m"
cyan="\033[36m"
white="\033[37m"

echo ""
echo -e  "${green}       _ __  ___ ___ "
echo -e  "${green}      | '_ \/ __/ __|"
echo -e  "${green}      | | | \__ \__ \\"
echo -e  "${green}      |_| |_|___/___/"
echo -e  "${blue}       Welcome My first program"
echo ""
```

The change is to use `\\"` instead of `\"`. This prints a literal backslash and then ends [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting), instead of printing a literal `"` and failing to end quoting. (The shell treats both [the backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character) and [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) specially under some circumstances.)